# Practical, Short example of Mixed Integer Conic Program

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, cone, teaching

Mixed Integer Conic Programs is a family of Mixed Integer Programs which are convex in all non integer variables. I am giving presentation on Mixed Integer technology. A large part of the presentation will be about MILP, it's tricks and common problem structures. I will also make people aware of MINLP by giving a practical non-convex MINLP. I aim to do the same with a convex MINLP. Is someone aware of an easy to explain[1] MIP using a Second-order, Rotated second-order, Positive semidefinite or Primal exponential which has a practical application?

[1] It should not involve power networks, trajectory optimisation and ideally fit on a slide. Why the cone is needed should be obvious from the problem description.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your opening sentence could be more accurately written as
Mixed Integer Conic Programs are a family of Mixed Integer Programs whose continuous relaxations are (convex) conic programs.

One easy to understand example is best variable subset selection by Mixed-Integer Least Squares, as presented in [BEST SUBSET SELECTION VIA A MODERN OPTIMIZATION LENS, D IMITRIS B ERTSIMAS, ANGELA K ING AND R AHUL M AZUMDER,The Annals of Statistics, 2016, Vol. 44, No. 2, 813–852](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-44/issue-2/Best-subset-selection-via-a-modern-optimization-lens/10.1214/15-AOS1388.pdf)

The [Mosek Modeling Cookbook version 3.2.3 Section 9.2 Mixed integer conic case studies](https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/mio.html#mixed-integer-conic-case-studies) has examples

- Wireless network design
- Portfolio optimization subject to transaction costs, cardinality constraints, and/or trading size constraints
- Convex piecewise linear regression

The [YALMIP wiki](https://yalmip.github.io/example/modellingif/) has an example of nonconvex regression arising from non-convex penalty function, which is handled as MISOCP.

[Applications and Solution Approaches for Mixed-Integer Semidefinite Programming,
Tristan Gally, joint work with Marc E. Pfetsch and Stefan Ulbrich](https://docs.mosek.com/generic/workshop/2018/mixed-int-conic/gally.pdf) has MISDP examples for

- Max-Cut (very cleverly, the non-convex rank constraint for the SDP can be relaxed (omitted) with no effect on optimal solution because every integer solution satisfies the omitted rank constraint; therefore the non-convexity has been moved from the rank constraint entirely to the integer (binary) constraints)
- Compressed Sensing
- Truss Topology Design.

Section 9.2 of [A Tutorial on Geometric Programming, S. Boyd, S.-J. Kim, L. Vandenberghe, and A. Hassibi](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/gp_tutorial.pdf) has a Mixed-Integer Geometric Programming example for Digital Circuit Gate Scaling in which the scale factors must take integer values. So this would be a Mixed-Integer Exponential Cone problem.

You may also find the video, [The conic advantage in MINLP, Henrik A. Friberg:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_ZF1Tr5Rc4) to be of interest.